# Wired connection not detecting after update

Tags: networking, ethernet

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, I have turned on pre-released updates in developers options. After the recent update Ubuntu is not detecting my wired internet connection. Everything was working fine before the update. I am also using Windows in dual boot and everything is working fine there.

Also there is no wired settings in network.

I just checked Ubuntu is also not detecting my sound card.

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7100fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
```

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

~$ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

~$ sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7100fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
```

shvmpc@shvmpc:~$ sudo apt install dkms r8168-dkms

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dkms is already the newest version (2.8.1-5ubuntu1).
r8168-dkms is already the newest version (8.048.00-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

shvmpc@shvmpc:~$ sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7100fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
```

Comment: **That's why you don't turn on pre-release updates. Really. Unless you wish to be a BETA tester.** Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: Well now I know

Comment: See my partial answer. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema /etc/network/interfaces 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7100fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff

Comment: Please don't use comments for such data. See Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: FYI: After pasting that kind of text into your question, select the pasted text, and then click on the {} icon to format it into human-readable text. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema Is this the correct file r8168-dkms_8.048.00-1_all.deb? I am unable to install it.

Comment: You need to install `dkms` first, then r8168-dkms. If you get any errors, tell me what they are.

Comment: See Update #2 in my answer.

Comment: @heynnema yeah that would be easier, thanks for your help sir, I really shouldn't be messing around like that

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema I have reinstalled ubuntu, everything is working fine now and pre-released updates is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re: *"I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, I have turned on pre-released updates in developers options."*

That's why you don't turn on pre-release updates. Really. Unless you wish to be a BETA tester.

---

Edit /etc/network/interfaces to look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Reboot.

---

**Update #1:**

Let's try and install an alternate ethernet driver...

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install dkms r8168-dkms

reboot
```

Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` again. (Not in the comments please).

Note: If you can't connect to the network via wireless, boot into Windows, go to the following web pages, download the files, copy them to a USB flash, and then in Ubuntu, install them with:

```
sudo apt install /path_to/filename.deb
```

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=dkms&searchon=names&suite=focal&section=all

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&section=all&arch=any&keywords=r8168-dkms&searchon=names

**Update #2:**

Best just to reinstall Ubuntu at this point. Make sure that pre-released updates is not enabled.